# Gazebo camera plugin error (VirtualBox, Kinetic)

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As I try to echo the image_raw topic of the camera, the simulation crashes:

> rostopic echo
> /robotino/camera1/image_raw WARNING:
> no messages received and simulated
> time is active. Is /clock being
> published?

> [ INFO] [1531314909.385823119,
> 0.033000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/' [ INFO]
> [1531314909.403410859, 0.033000000]:
> Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>,
> set to "" [ INFO]
> [1531314909.709798404, 0.067000000]:
> waitForService: Service
> [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is
> now available. [ INFO]
> [1531314909.893404319, 0.197000000]:
> Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
> gzserver:
> /build/ogre-1.9-mqY1wq/ogre-1.9-1.9.0+dfsg1/OgreMain/src/OgreRenderSystem.cpp:546:
> virtual void
> Ogre::RenderSystem::setDepthBufferFor(Ogre::RenderTarget*):
> Assertion `bAttached && "A new
> DepthBuffer for a RenderTarget was
> created, but after creation" "it says
> it's incompatible with that RT"'
> failed. Aborted (core dumped)
> [gazebo-2] process has died [pid
> 13310, exit code 134, cmd
> /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver
> -e ode /home/ulysses/catkin_ws/src/robotino_gazebo/worlds/robotino.world
> __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/ulysses/.ros/log/6cd65eba-850c-11e8-804e-08002782662e/gazebo-2.log]. log file:
> /home/ulysses/.ros/log/6cd65eba-850c-11e8-804e-08002782662e/gazebo-2*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19989/gazebo-camera-plugin-error-(virtualbox,-kinetic)/) by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) on 2018-07-11**:
echo "export SVGA_VGPU10=0" >> ~/.bashrc

Does not help

**Comment by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) on 2018-07-11**:
So I must to find somewhere OgreMain/src/OgreRenderSystem.cpp:546 and change there FSAA, according to previous questions, but I don't know, where this file is and how I must recompile gazebo. Maybe there is some way just to update the gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Delete ros - reinstall gazebo7 fresh - install ros

---

Originally posted by [DoctorUlysses](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5409/doctorulysses/) with karma: 11 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0